# Why are point-files cut at tiles-borders?

Tags: tiles, tilemill, svg, cartocss

I'm placing a SVG in Tilemill via a point with lat and long.

So far that works great but when the tile the point is located in ends, the image is not rendered.

Is this a bug? Can I do something about it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a bug, this is a limitation of how tiled web maps get rendered. You may be able to work around this by adjusting the *buffer* and *metatile* settings in TileMill, but depending on how big your SVG is at some point you will still hit a limit of how large a marker you can place on a single point.

Here is the documentation about buffers and metatiles in TileMill: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/metatiles/

The main takeaway from this is that both increased buffers and increased metatile sizes will help. But buffers can only be expanded out to a maximum of 256px, and even with larger metatiles there may still be points that fall near the edge of the metatile - if the marker is much wider or taller than 256px then it can still get cut off.

If your SVG is quite large it may make sense to export it as a raster image and [georeference it](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) instead of using it as a point marker. Or, depending on what you're doing, maybe [the georeferencing isn't even important?](http://www.macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html)